# Managing a user's crontab in a dotfiles repository

Tags: makefile, cron, dotfiles, stow

[Many developers](https://github.com/search?q=dotfiles) maintain a dotfile repository, keeping all their configurations in a single space that can be easily synced among different machines. What I haven't seen so far is people maintaining their crontabs in the dotfile repository.

Regardless if you find the idea itself useful or not, what would be a convenient way to manage one's crontab in the dotfile repository as well? In [my dotfiles repository](https://github.com/venthur/dotfiles), the management of the symlinks is handled by [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) and a simple `Makefile` that wraps the `stow`-commands like so:

```
all:
    stow --verbose --target=$$HOME --restow */

delete:
    stow --verbose --target=$$HOME --delete */
```

GNU Stow obviously will not work for crontabs. How could I integrate the rollout, update and removal of a crontab in this setup?

Comment: When creating a new tag it's always appreciated if you also add a [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stow/info) and preferably, a description.

Comment: I don't have tag wiki edit privileges yet, and when submitting a proposal, the edit queue is always full, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

`crontab` has a usage of the form:

```bash
crontab [-u user] file
```

which will install a new crontab from some named file. You can place this step in your Makefile and install a file committed to the repository.